# How to put Excel as a sink in Azure Data Factory /Azure mapping dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Its kind of weird that i could not find Excel as a sink. How to write the file to Excel using DataFactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel is yet not a supported sink in Azure data factory.
Its is not an out of box functionality
You would have to write your own custom logic either via Azure function,logic app etc

Comment: Can you explain that how to do that with Function apps /Logic apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used, but it seems this company is sharing for free a package that you can install in your ADF instance to export Excel files.

https://invati.ai/software-development-accelerators/excel-writer-for-azure-data-factory/

Note that although the package is free, hosting it in your Azure instance may incur in charges.