# Sink as Excel in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy the SQL table into an Excel format and when I saw the SDF we don't have an Excel as sink. Does anyone know what should we do any way we can implement so I can copy data into Excel format

How can I use Excel as a sink in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Excel is not supported in ADF for Sink, only for source. see this question for some ideas on how to go around this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721818/how-to-put-excel-as-a-sink-in-azure-data-factory-azure-mapping-dataflow . Also, you can save as CSV, and then open in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Excel file is not supported as sink in copy activity. You can raise a feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).

As a workaround, you can try Databricks or Azure functions to read the data from SQL table and write it as Excel file. Call those using Databricks Notebook activity or Azure functions activity in ADF.

This is a Demo using Databricks notebook. You need to mount the target to `dbfs` fir this.

first install xlsxwriter.

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

**Code:**

```
%python
#read the SQL table as pyspark dataframe using JDBC
Server_name = "<server_name>.database.windows.net"
Database = "<database_name>"
Port = "<port_name>"
user_name = "<user_name>"
Password = "<password>"
jdbc_Url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(Server_name, Port,Database)
conn_properties = {
"user" : user_name,
"password" : Password,
"driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
df=spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_Url,table="sample1",properties=conn_properties)

#Convert pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe and write it to excel file
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
pandas_df.to_excel('excel1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Now, move the excel file to mount location.

```
%sh
sudo  mv excel1.xlsx /dbfs/mnt/data1/
```

[image]

Now, Execute this Notebook using Notebook activity in ADF.

[image]

**Excel file:**

[image]

You can do the same like above using python code in Azure functions.